# Configure ssh config file for certain command

Tags: ssh

My problem is the following. I wish to configure the .ssh/config as such, that when I write

> ssh exampleX

It is the same as if I wrote

> ssh -i /path/to/key.pem user@address

Note that the above command works.

Following the answers [here](https://superuser.com/questions/503687/whats-the-difference-between-host-and-hostname-in-ssh-config) I tried to create the file as

```
Host exampleX
    HostName address
    User user
    IdentityFile /path/to/key.pem
```

Taken from

> ssh -i /path/to/key.pem user@address

Yet when I run

> ssh exampleX

I get the error

> ssh: Could not resolve hostname exampleX: Name or service not known

But if I manually run the command

> ssh -i /path/to/key.pem user@address

everything works. Where am I making the mistake in creating the file?

#### Edit

If I run

```
sudo ssh exampleX -v
```

I get the output

```
OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.2, OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
ssh: Could not resolve hostname exampleX: Name or service not known
```

but if I run it without sudo i get a longer stream, that ends with

```
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /path/to/key.pem
Load key "/path/to/key.pem": Permission denied
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey).
```

#### Edit 2

Due to some confusion , I restate my question

What does the config file has to look like, so that running

```
ssh exampleX
```

will work the same as running

```
ssh -i /path/to/key.pem user@address
```

Comment: Double check you really edited `~/.ssh/config` - remember about `~` part, this file should be in your home directory, not a current directory. Make sure that your `ssh` client uses this file - post output of `ssh exampleX -v`.

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk I edited the question and added the output. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you run your command through `sudo`, you are using the `.ssh/config` file that corresponds to the user that `sudo` runs as. If you *really* need to run this ssh command as root, you need the configuration added to `~root/.ssh/config` instead of `~/.ssh/config`.

If possible, run your `ssh` as a normal user, not as `root`.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I do not know how it addresses my issue though... What am I to do, so that running "ssh exampleX" will work as specified in the question?

Comment: Please look at Edit 2 to my question. Thank you very much for your time. EDIT: I run it as sudo, because the key requires it to.

Comment: I figured it out, because of your answer. I will accept and upvote it soon. Please add to your answer (for other users) that the problem is that the file needs sudo, because it is owned by root. Which is revealed by the error messages. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

(Since the question was edited, I edited accordingly my answer)

1. Check the permissions of the file **~/.ssh/config**: it must have strict permissions: read/write for the user, and not accessible by others, as explained in the **man** page.
2. Check also you have read access (as a user) to the file **/path/to/key.pem**. The debug option you used with **ssh** suggests you don't have.

Comment: Are you sure it *must* be indented? Because I'm not sure.

Comment: @PierreFrançois My code is indented, I had made a mistake when posting the question (the use of quote instead of code, ignores the indent)